# Error-raising procedure and trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, dml

I am trying to prevent a user from running DML commands on the `Employees` table in SQL Server in certain period of the week.

What I have been trying is to achieve this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE secure_dml
AS
BEGIN
    IF CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 8) NOT BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '18:00:00'
       OR FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'ddd') IN ('Mon', 'Sun') 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('You may only make changes during normal office hours', 1, 1)
    END
END;
```

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER secure_employees 
ON employees
INSTEAD OF INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC secure_dml;
END;
```

but it seems not to be working for me. I still can update the table `Employees` at all times.

Am I missing something, what should I change in the code?

**UPDATE:**

Then as was suggested I put the logic inside the trigger itself as follows:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER secure_employees 
ON employees
INSTEAD OF INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 8) NOT BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '18:00:00'
        OR FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'ddd') IN ('Mon', 'Sun') 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('You may only make changes during normal office hours', 1, 1);
    END
END;
```

But it does not prevent me from updating of the table anyway.

Then I tried as follows:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER secure_employees 
ON employees
INSTEAD OF INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 8) NOT BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '18:00:00'
        OR FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'ddd') IN ('Mon', 'Sun') 
        THROW 50005, 'You may only make changes during normal office hours', 1;
END;
```

but as you may guess again without success.

Comment: Why use a procedure to put the obscure logic somewhere else? Why not just do the check in the `TRIGGER` and `THROW` the error there?

Comment: @Larnu I have tried your suggestion, unfortunately without success

Comment: You're still using `RAISERROR`.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable suggestion! 
Apologies for bothering you and making you guessing.
I guess I found out why the code did not do what I wanted to. 
There was damn ```DISABLE TRIGGER secure_employees ON employees;``` command way below the  place of declaring trigger and I missed it :(

Comment: An even better reason to do this logic another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I suggest you use `THROW` here and put the logic in the `TRIGGER`:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER secure_employees ON employees
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    IF CONVERT(time(0),GETDATE()) < '08:00:00'
    OR CONVERT(time(0),GETDATE()) > '18:00:00'
    OR (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 IN (1,2) --This is language safe
       THROW 50001, N'You may only make changes during normal office hours.',16;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need either a procedure or an `INSTEAD OF` trigger. You can just use an `AFTER` trigger

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER secure_employees ON employees
  AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF CONVERT(time, GETDATE()) NOT BETWEEN CONVERT(time, '08:00:00') AND CONVERT(time, '18:00:00')
        OR (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 IN (1, 2) 
BEGIN
    THROW 500001, 'You may only make changes during normal office hours', 1;
END;
```

You don't need to roll back the transaction, `THROW` will do that for you.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c739af2d10f29d555738cac78e593fc)

---

I suggest you find a different way of enforcing this kind of business restriction on employees, SQL is not really the place for it.

Comment: I guess begin after ```IF``` is misplaced, since it shows syntax error.

Comment: Works fine, not sure what your issue is https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c739af2d10f29d555738cac78e593fc

Comment: I think it's a parsing problem in [SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll7GX.png)/[ADS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svUsn.png), @Charlieface . Both report the error, but they don't occur on actual run.